# Cannot use Components/Service/Repository in Controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a well configurated dao layer(I've created test to check it), and now I would like to integrate my project with spring mvc.

I've added this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.szymon.controller")
public class WebMvcConfig {
        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

            return viewResolver;
        }
    }

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

And my controller looks like:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private MeetingRepository meetingRepository;


    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("message", "message");
    model.addAttribute("meeting", meetingRepository.findOne(1L));
    return "helloWorld";
}

@RequestMapping("/hel")
public String hel(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "message");
    return "helloWorld2";
}
```

}

After commenting meetingRepository field and helloWorld() method servlet works fine. But if its not commented it doesn't working:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.szymon.repository.MeetingRepository com.szymon.controller.HelloWorldController.meetingRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.szymon.repository.MeetingRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:536)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.szymon.repository.MeetingRepository com.szymon.controller.HelloWorldController.meetingRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.szymon.repository.MeetingRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:536)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.szymon.repository.MeetingRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:536)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It looks, that spring is not making beans when using spring mvc. How should i configure my application for working properly?

**EDIT** 
MeetingRepository class:

```
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting, Long> {
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.szymon.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataAccessConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("postgres");
        return localEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

It's working well, because I've tested it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DataAccessConfig.class)
public class MeetingRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MeetingRepository meetingRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
        meeting.setAddedDate(new Date());
        meeting.setMeetingDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000));
        meeting.setNotes("Moje pierwsze spotkanie.");
        meeting.setPlace("Pokoj 200");

        meetingRepository.save(meeting);
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is your MeetingRepository.java? Is that scanned by \@ComponentScan, do you mark it as \@Repository ?

Comment: Try to post the class MeetingRepository

Comment: @VinhNT I have it in com.szymon.repository. 
It is configured as JpaRepository. In my config class it's set up to scan. And it's working, because I've tested it with Junit.

Comment: MeetingRepository should be marked similar like

@Repository
public MeetingRepository .....{
...
}

Comment: @nowszy94 Can you try placing `@EnableTransactionManagement` and 
`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages=...)` on the `WebMvcConfig.java` class and place `@Repository` on the `MeetingRepository` class.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I placed it, and tried one more time. This time Spring said, i have no entityManagerFactory. I coppied bean's declaration from DataAccessConfig to WebMvcConfig and it's working now.

But why? I've created that bean's deffinitions already, why it's necessary to creat it again? It makes no sense.

Comment: @nowszy94 Although `DataAccessConfig` class is marked as `@Configuration` it is not being referenced in your `WebInitializer` class. The `WebInitializer` class is only referencing `WebMvcConfig` and so only that is considered. If you want you can specify `DataAccessConfig` along with `WebMvcConfig` using `ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class, DataAccessConfig.class);`.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu It works perfect now! Thank you very much. I spend on this problem many hours. :)
One more question. If in WebInitializer im initializing all beans, and all spring magic, shouldn't this class be named different?

Comment: @nowszy94 I would prefer to separate bean intialization from `WebIntializer`. Place the bean initialization (`@Configuration`...) in a separate class and reference that in the `WebInitializer` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages=...)` on the `WebMvcConfig.java` class and place `@Repository` on the `MeetingRepository class`.

Although `DataAccessConfig` class is marked as `@Configuration` it is not being referenced in your `WebInitializer` class. The `WebInitializer` class is only referencing `WebMvcConfig` and so only that is considered.

If you want you can specify `DataAccessConfig` along with `WebMvcConfig` using `ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class, DataAccessConfig.class);`. That should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your Repository interface like this

```
@Repository
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting, Long> {
}
```

Comment: You dont need to mark it as @Repository. If you implement it like this, it's repository by default.